# A common header for 400 reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am developing an ERP system that has more that **400 reports** in **2 languages**.

How can i make a **common report header** for all of them so that when i change the company logo and name, it is applied to the 400+ reports at once?

Is there any better way to make the report bi-Language other that making two reports?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you specifically mention only wanted to change the report header and logo.  You could simply populate them from a field in a database somewhere, based on a parameter in the report that determines which to show.

Then just copy/paste the header to all reports and from then on, you can change the header details at will.

Comment: That will solve my problem, along with using a template

Answer (score 1):

For new reports you could build a template. Assuming you are using Visual Studio/BIDS the templates are found here...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject

(swap out the 10.0 for which version of Visual Studio you have)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use 
[Report Parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parts-report-builder-and-ssrs).

A report part is published to the server similar in concept to a shared data source or data set.  They can be inserted into your report to facilitate consistent presentation of information.

Once inserted, they are directly embedded into the report, rather than a reference to an object like a subreport is.  This allows the report part to be customized if needed for the report and ensures good performance of the report part.  However it is loosely coupled with the published definition.

If you need to update the report part definition, any reports that use it will still contain the old definition until they are opened, refreshed and republished.